# How can I make an invisible, yet clickable button in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to be able to have a button that is not visible, but able to trigger a click event when clicked.

I'm looking at this page [MSDN: System.windows.visibilty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx) and it seems that buttons can have three visibility states. Visible, Hidden and Collapsed. When the button is Hidden or Collapsed, I can't see it (which is good) but I can't click it (which is bad).

Does anyone have a way that I can make clickable invisible element in my XAML file?

Comment: Does it really have to be a `Button`? You can receive click events from pretty much any control.

Comment: Well now this would be useless. Ever heard of discoverability as a design principle?

Comment: @Anon: That is not the case at all. The click event is almost exclusive to the Button control.

Comment: @CodyGray - If someone is required to have an image 'hot spot', so to speak, then a click event on the image as a whole would be useless.  Ideally, they would be individual elements (each with events that can be associated to it) but it isn't always possible.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try setting the Button's `Opacity`...

```
<Button Opacity="0" />
```

Comment: As an alternate, use Background="#01000000", setting the background color to an almost-transparent color.

Comment: And to get rid of the dotted line focus rectangle set `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"`

Comment: Another little tip.  If you add the <Button> element last in a <Grid> the button will be on top and allow you to cover over the other elements making the entire grid clickable.

Comment: One more tip. The button won't receive a Click event if its contents have manipulations enabled. But you can use a [StylusSystemGesture](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27272024/603828) event instead.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use the `Opacity` property?