# WPF TouchUp not firing when parent manipulation is enabled

Tags: wpf, touch

I have a Canvas, with one child control. The child controls receives all PreviewTouchDown and PreviewTouchUp events fine - but after enabling Manipulation (`IsManipulationEnabled` = true) on the Canvas, only the "down" events get fired on child object, but the TouchUp and PreviewTouchUp events doesn't fire at all..

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 7):

You need to set `IsManipulationEnabled` to `true` on the child element, too.

---

The relationship between touch and manipulation events is explained in [Input Overview / Touch and Manipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx#touch_and_manipulation), section **The Relationship Between Touch and Manipulation Events**:

> A UIElement can always receive touch events. When the
>   IsManipulationEnabled property is set to true, a UIElement can receive
>   both touch and manipulation events. If the TouchDown event is not
>   handled (that is, the Handled property is false), the manipulation
>   logic captures the touch to the element and generates the manipulation
>   events. If the Handled property is set to true in the TouchDown event,
>   the manipulation logic does not generate manipulation events. The
>   following illustration shows the relationship between touch events and
>   manipulation events.

Touch and manipulation events

[image: Touch and manipulation events]

Comment: So there's no option to get them both?

Comment: Just found some code of my own where I manually call `CaptureTouch` from a `PreviewTouchDown` handler that also sets `Handled = true`. And there is also a `PreviewTouchUp` handler. Unfortunately I can't test it right now, but I will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: OK, Great if you can do that.. but don't mind if it's too troublesome, as I already dumped the whole idea of using manipulation and decided to calculate scale and rotations myself in the touchmove -event.

Comment: Just did a quick test. If you set `IsManipulationEnabled = true` on the child element, it will get all touch (and of course manipulation) events.

Comment: Link to section **The Relationship Between Touch and Manipulation Events**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/input-overview#the-relationship-between-touch-and-manipulation-events

Answer (score 3):

For a workaround, you can capture **"Stylus tap"** events just fine if the parent element has `IsManipulationEnabled = true`:

```cs
....

MyChildElement.StylusSystemGesture += MyChildElement_StylusSystemGesture;
    
....
    
void MyChildElement_StylusSystemGesture(object sender, StylusSystemGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SystemGesture == SystemGesture.Tap)
            //Do something
    }
```

Comment: And a year after that, you saved my sanity! Finally, I can detect "clicks" on an element that has manipulations enabled on it. An enclosing button wouldn't even detect a click, but the stylus-gesture works.