# touch manipulation stops mouse event promotion WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, touch, mouse

Currently everything in my WPF application is bound to mouse events. This works great even with touch because touch events get promoted to mouse events. So taps get promoted to left clicks and long taps to right clicks. However when I enable touch manipulation in my WPF control with IsManimulationEnabled="True" this breaks the auto event promotion from touch to mouse. How can I keep this promotion?

Comment: I don't think you can, that's the point of the property.

Comment: The point of ManipulationEnabled is to provide an easy way to pan swipe and pinch zoom not to prevent all other inputs from occuring. If that was the intent then its a poor implementation since it does not provide tap and tap & hold event capture. It even preempts touch events so I can't even implement my own tap and tap & hold.

Comment: Maybe [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15460574/4265041) will help.